# NodeJS: Print colored text from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, colors

I recently make a CLI project called ani-cli and im working on colors configuration

I want to read a JSON object that contains terminal color code for example
`\\033[33m\\x1b[33m` (I put double backslash because if i put it single, the JSON parser will throw an error and not parsing)

I make a simple code to read JSON object

```js
let colors = fs.readFile("colors.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err){
        return null;
    } else {
        let obj = JSON.parse(data);
        let title = obj["title"];
        // console.log(title.toString() + "Hi");
        console.log(title + "HI");
    }
})
```

when i run the code, it's not printing the color, only the text

[Screenshot of the running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMvf9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how string escaping works in JSON files, using just a JSON file would be difficult.

If you do want to have your colors file separate, I would recommend you have it in a separate js file:

```
module.exports = {
  reset: "\x1b[0m",

  title: "\x1b[33m",
  red: "\x1b[31m",
  green: "\x1b[32m",
};
```

In your main js file, you can then require. the module or even shake the module to get what you want:

```
const { title, reset, red, green } = require("./colors");

console.log(title, "HI!", reset);
console.log("I am of normal color");
console.log(red, "I am red", reset);
console.log(green, "I am green", reset);
```

This also allows you to use dynamic color keys if you ever need to:

```
const colors = require("./colors");
const colorsArr = ['red', 'title', 'green'];

for (color of colorsArr) {
    console.log(colors[color], `I am color: ${color}`, colors.reset)
}
```

Always remember to reset your colors! :)

```
const { reset } = require("./colors");
console.log(reset);
```

Comment: thanks, it works using seperate javascript file 